# Wordpress Dokan vendor store translate with Polylang

Tags: wordpress, polylang, dokan

I want to add translation for the supplier store, but the store page does not have a translation function[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx9vd.png)

I haven't found a plugin to solve this problem. I found the WPML plugin but that doesn't work either.

Comment: In settings you have to change from not translate to translate for specific post type and taxonomy.